# npm init @builder.io FAILS

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, builder.io

I'm building a web app using Builder.io.
Earlier today everything worked fine. I thought it would be a good idea to install 'pnpm'.

When I tried to run the command 'npm init @builder.io' it failed with an nasty error message. I figured since the only thing that changed was me installing 'pnpm', I'll go head uninstalling it and everything should go back to normal. Boy was I wrong lol

I used Brew to uninstall node and to reinstall it and it still didn't work. I think it has something to do with my $PATH, but not sure. Unfortunately there's not a lot of information on Google about this topic.

Now after I create a new nextJS app, using 'npx create-next-app' and then I go into that directory to run 'npm init @builder.io' I get the following error:

```
sh: create-builder: command not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /Users/dspamer/code/datagun.io
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-builder

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/dspamer/.npm/_logs/2023-12-13T22_25_37_537Z-debug-0.log
```

Does anyone understand this and know what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

---UPADTE---
After more searching I found the answer here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/error-cannot-find-module-node-npm-error-solved/

To resolve this I ran the command: `npm install builder.io`